# Using c# to add users to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to use c# to add users to active directory. I've tried using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and I've added the necessary references but for some reason it won't recognize `.CommitChanges()`, `.Invoke()`, or `.Exists()`. Here is the code that I've been trying to work on. The exact error that I get is:

> CS0012 The type 'Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I added a reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll, is there any other reference I need to add to system?

This is .NET

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace Test
{
    class Class1
    {
        public struct UserInfo
        {
            public string userName;
            public string sAMAccountName;
            public string password;
            public string firstName;
            public string lastName;
            public string fullName;
            public string principalName;
            public string ou;
            public string description;
        }

        public static void  Main()
        {
            string uFirstName = "John";
            string uLastName = "Test";
            string uUserName = uFirstName + "." + uLastName;
            string uOu = "OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=";
            string uSamAccount = uUserName;
            string uPassword = "password";

            UserInfo newUserInfo;
            newUserInfo.firstName = uFirstName;
            newUserInfo.lastName = uLastName;
            newUserInfo.fullName = uFirstName + uLastName;

            newUserInfo.userName = uUserName;
            newUserInfo.principalName = uUserName + "@rc";
            newUserInfo.ou = uOu;
            newUserInfo.description = "STUDENT";
            newUserInfo.sAMAccountName = uSamAccount;
            newUserInfo.password = uPassword;

            DirectoryEntry adUserFolder = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=, OU=, OU=, DC=, DC=");

            DirectoryEntry newUser = adUserFolder.Children.Add("CN=" + newUserInfo.userName, "User");

            // Checks for duplicate entries
            if (DirectoryEntry.Exists(newUser.Path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The user: " + newUser.Username + " already exists, the new entry will be deleted.");
                adUserFolder.Children.Remove(new DirectoryEntry(newUser.Path));
            }
            else
            { 
                return; 
            }

            newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = newUserInfo.sAMAccountName;
            newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = newUserInfo.firstName;
            newUser.Properties["surName"].Value = newUserInfo.lastName;
            newUser.Properties["Path"].Value = newUserInfo.ou;
            newUser.Properties["Description"].Value = newUserInfo.description;
            newUser.Properties["Password"].Value = newUserInfo.password;

            newUser.CommitChanges();

            newUser.Invoke("setpassword", "password"); 
            newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200;

            newUser.CommitChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("User: " + newUserInfo.userName + " has been successfully created!");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: As said in the error, did you add a reference to "System", version 4.0.0?

Comment: Is this .NET or .NET Core?